# js получить время

Tags: javascript

Нужно вытащить отсюда время https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213 и записать в переменную как это сделать?

Comment: Отправляете запрос, получаете json документ, парсите его и вытаскиваете время.

Comment: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213', true); как  дальше?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731915/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-time Кажется, здесь точно такой же вопрос.