# javascript получить time

Tags: javascript, json

Хочу получить массив и выдернуть оттуда время

```
$.get('https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213', function(data){
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
})
```

пишет ошибку

> Failed to load https://yandex.com/time/sync.json?geo=213: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.ru' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: У вашего домена нет прав на отправку запросов в yandex.com/time/...

Comment: есть ли аналог  yandex.com/time/ ??

Comment: посмотрите на time100.ru.... там у них вроде даже api есть.... источник: http://javascript.ru/forum/showthread.php?p=436963

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [javascript получить точное московское время](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731945/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f)

Comment: Закрывающим: этот вопрос не является дубликатом, так как речь здесь идёт о доступе к конкретному сервису времени, а не получению времени вообще.